# Plotting vertical/horizontal lines that intersect line graph on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, geom-hline, geom-vline

The following code produces the following plot:

```
time_step <- c(1:5, 1:5)

perceived_signal_slow <- c(1:5, cumsum(1:5))

signal_name <- c("perceived","perceived","perceived","perceived","perceived","accumulated","accumulated","accumulated","accumulated","accumulated")

df <- cbind(perceived_signal_slow, signal_name, time_step)

df <- as.data.frame(df)

df$time_step <- as.numeric(as.character(df$time_step))
df$perceived_signal_slow <- as.numeric(as.character(df$perceived_signal_slow))

ggplot(df, aes(x = time_step, y = signal, colour = signal_name)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 4, colour = "black", size = 1, alpha = .4) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 10, colour = "black", size = 1, alpha = .4) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 4, colour = "black", size = 1, alpha = .4)
```

[image: plot]
However **I want to limit the vertical and horizontal lines** so that they don't travel any further once they hit the accumulated and perceived lines of my graph. Does anybody know how I could alter my code to do this?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Maybe restrict the plotting area to the minimum and maximum of your data (such as (`x=1` and `5`)? You can check `xlim()` or `ylim()` attributes in `ggplot2` help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `geom_segment`:

```
time_step <- c(1:5, 1:5)

perceived_signal_slow <- c(1:5, cumsum(1:5))

signal_name <- c("perceived","perceived","perceived","perceived","perceived","accumulated","accumulated","accumulated","accumulated","accumulated")

df <- cbind(perceived_signal_slow, signal_name, time_step)

df <- as.data.frame(df)

df$time_step <- as.numeric(as.character(df$time_step))
df$signal <- as.numeric(as.character(df$perceived_signal_slow))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = time_step, y = signal, colour = signal_name)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_segment(x = 4, xend=4, y = -Inf, yend=10, colour = "black", size = 0.2) +
  geom_segment(x= -Inf, xend=4, y = 10, yend = 10, colour = "black", size = 0.2) +
  geom_segment(x= -Inf, xend=4, y = 4, yend = 4, colour = "black", size = 0.2)
```

This produces:

[image]